# Large zip file is not extracting on my server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to extract zip files on my server using PHP. Small size zip files will extract successfully but when I try to extract large zip file, I get the following problem:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@extremenox.co and inform them of the time the
>   error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused
>   the error. More information about this error may be available in the
>   server error log. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request.

Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(1);
set_time_limit(3600);
$file=ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/wp-cloud-safe/lib/www.extremenox.co_19_10_2015_04_%i_1445259414.zip';
if(file_exists($file)){
  $zip2 = new ZipArchive;
  if ($zip2->open($file) === TRUE) 
  {
   $zip2->extractTo("/");
  $zip2->close();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are either running into memory issues or timeout issues. Try adding the following to your php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time = 60
memory_limit = 512M ;
```

You can reduce/increase each value in the above until you reach a point where you don't get the error anymore. Keep in mind that it's better to use a shell script to do this in order not to run into the PHP limitations.

Note: The above values are pretty high, so again, you should try to reduce them as much as possible until the error is no more.